# How do I prevent the text overflow in menu?

Tags: menus, css

The text in the navigation menu on [my site](https://passionwp.com) is overflowing the container in the desktop version (no problem on mobile).

How do I wrap the text to prevent the overflow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your browser's inspector <kbd>f12</kbd>, you can see your list items have this CSS applied...

```
.sf-menu li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You need to change it to...

```
.sf-menu li {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

If you already created a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) you can make the change there.  Otherwise, in the admin go to Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS and add the above CSS.

Comment: This worked just fine. Problem solved. Many thanks.